# Python: iterate through two lists and write them to outfile on the same line

Tags: python, list, zip

I would like to iterate through two lists simultaneously and write each item from both lists, tab-separated on the same line.

```
word = ['run', 'windless', 'marvelous']
pron = ['rVn', 'wIndl@s', 'mArv@l@s']
```

Desired output:

```
run  rVn
windless  wIndl@s
marvelous  mArv@l@s
```

I tried using `zip` but it doesn't let me write to file:

```
for w, p in zip(word, pron):
   outfile.write(w, p)

TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `zip`.  It's that the `write` method of a file object takes a single string.  You are trying to pass two strings.  Have you considered using `print`?

Comment: print works great, but I really want to save to a file though -- surely there must be a way?

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

write only takes one argument as a parameter. To write both variables in the same line, change:

```
outfile.write(w, p)
```

such that it is one string with a tab and a newline:

```
outfile.write("{}\t{}\n".format(w,p))
```

Comment: hmm I get the error: `ValueError: zero length field name in format`

Comment: @user1899415 You must be on python2.6.  Try `outfile.write("{0}\t{1}\n".format(w,p))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path. You just need to give the write() function a single line to write.

Like this:

```
for w, p in zip(word, pron):
    outfile.write("%s, %s" % (w, p))
```

Comment: This gives the output: `'run', 'windless', 'marvelous', 'rVn', 'wIndl@s', 'mArv@l@s'`

Comment: @user1899415 I don't think the output you showed is possible with the code in this answer...  There are too many commas, and the output should *definitely* not have any single quotes.  Are you sure you are using this code exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make life easier for yourself you can use the print statement/function.

[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print):

```
print >>outfile, w, p
```

[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print)  (or Python 2 using `from __future__ import print_function` at the top):

```
print(w, p, file=outfile)
```

This way you can avoid manually adding the '\n' or converting everything to a single string.